# System of differential equations of the 2nd order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How does one solve a system of linear 2nd order differential equations. I know how to solve for systems of first order linear differential equations. Is there any characteristic equations I can use or can we transform this to a first order system?

take this for example,
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}
\begin{bmatrix} 
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
 x_3 \\
 x_4 \\
 x_5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
 -20 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 10 & -20 & 10 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 10 & -20 & 10 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 10 & -20 & 10\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & -10\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
 x_1 \\
 x_2 \\
 x_3 \\
 x_4 \\
 x_5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix} 
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
f(t)
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have a system $$\ddot x=Ax+b,$$ then an eigen-decomposition of $A$ will decouple that as well, if $A=UDU^{-1}$, then with $x=Uy$ you get $$\ddot y=Dy+u^{-1}b,$$ which is a system of independent scalar equations.

Here $U$ is should be related to the matrix of the discrete sine transform.

Comment: Do you have any references I can read on this matter?